# Dockerfile for tensorflow GPU + opencv3 + Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: docker, opencv, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am a bit confused. Now I am not using a dockerfile but the command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(realpath ~/path/of/directory):/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter
```

But I don't have access to cv2 module. Maybe add something to the run command or write my own dockerfile? but I don't know how. Do I have to pip install and RUN tensorflow GPU and jupyter notebook in the dockerfile ?

Comment: Anyone who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this image *tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter* has installed opencv and python module cv2.
If it doesn't you should find another image or install it by yourself.

Comment: This is the image I am using in the docker run command above but it doesn't contain opencv unfortunately

Comment: You can build new image. It will be based on tensorflow image + you should write some commands. You can use this example: https://github.com/Borda/docker_python-opencv-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow image by default does not have OpenCV in it.

There are two ways you can set it up :

A - Setup tensorflow docker container and then install using commands

OR

B - Create a docker file which takes tensorflow image as base image and install opencv using commands while building the image.

Please refer to the below link to do the same.

https://github.com/fbcotter/docker-tensorflow-opencv

https://github.com/fbcotter/docker-tensorflow-opencv/blob/master/Dockerfile